# Available Literature about Mathematical Origami

Tags: reference-request, origami

I'm interested in math and origami and I was wondering about where I would find the available literature on stuff like tessellations. Sorry if this is a kind of vague question...

Comment: I think I saw a TED talk (or similar) about using optimization to find the best folds, etc. Might be relevant. I will see if I can dredge up anything from my email history.

Comment: Here you are: https://www.ted.com/talks/robert_lang_folds_way_new_origami

Comment: Not exactly origami but somewhat related, don't miss Martin Gardner's book on hexaflexagons.

Comment: Why the close votes? Seems like a reasonable question.

Comment: @aschepler As it happens, I was just looking for the old Martin Gardner column on the "flapping bird" in SciAm, but I guess it's behind some paywall nowadays. Still, some related reading and pointers can be found at [Martin Gardner and Paperfolding](http://www.britishorigami.info/academic/lister/martin_gardner.php).

Comment: @copper.hat It can't really be answered.

Comment: It can gather enough information to be useful. Certainly more than another $-{ 1\over 12}$ inquiry...

Comment: Tomoko Fuse has written a few books on "unit origami" which can be used to create lots of 3D shapes, including platonic and archimedean solids.

Comment: Check out Erik Demaine's course/text on geometric folding: http://courses.csail.mit.edu/6.849/fall10/